# Voting result when majority points to unclassified

Tags: classification

What is **common approach** when dealing with classifier ensembles and majorityvoting when majority of classifier points to "unclassified".
Lets say, We have ensemble consisting of 5 classifiers, 4 does not recognize the object and one classifies as class A. 
Shoud the overall result be class A or unclassified?

Comment: could you add more detail? how are the classifiers leading to "unclassified"? what classifier method are you using? shouldn't they always give _some_ result?

Answer (score 0):

In classification problem objects **always** belong to one of the classes. That way objects, which you name "unclassified" are also belong to the class, which does not include any objects from your listed classes. Then, if the majority of your classifiers voted for an object to be "unclassified", you should choose that option and treat it like another class.